# How can I simulate an app getting killed in the background?

Tags: android

I'm trying to reproduce a crash that only happens when the OS terminates the app in the background (but still shows up in the app switcher). When the user goes back into the app, the app crashes.

My question is, how can I simulate the OS terminating an app in the background? I imagine this can happen if it's taking up too many resources or if the Android device is running low on power/memory/etc.

I've tried issuing the following ADB command:

```
adb shell am kill com.quidsi.diapers
```

Is there a better way to simulate this scenario?

Comment: onDestroy() method inside your Activity?

Comment: Might want to try Developer Options->Apps->Don't keep Activities, or change the Background Process limit. Don't forget to put it back to the original state when done - else you may think other weird things are going on with your device.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm debugging a similar kind of issue where a I believe a MediaStream is not being destroyed if a user kills a PWA by swiping up but does destroy it if the user navigates away from a react component that handles cleanup. I think the cleanup is not working as expected, only on Safari PWA if the user swipes up to kill the app.